# Getting 'True' values in Column instead of Original Values

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby, data-science

[CODE from Github named: EPL_Prediction](https://github.com/rsibi/epl-prediction-2017)
[DOwnload The dataset i am using 2016/2017](http://www.football-data.co.uk/spainm.php)
I am getting 'True' value in Columns instead of Team Names 
like : Barcelona , Real madrid

It is showing True in Every Column of Team.

The codes is like this:

```
        res_home = res_16.groupby('HomeTeam')
        res_away = res_16.groupby('AwayTeam')

        res_home.HomeTeam.all().values
        #list (res_home)[4]
        ##table_16.Team = res_home.HomeTeam.unique().values
        #table_16

        array([True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
               True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True])

        res_home = res_16.groupby('HomeTeam')
        res_away = res_16.groupby('AwayTeam')

        table_16.Team = res_home.HomeTeam.all().values
        table_16.Team

        0  True
        1  True
        2  True
        3  True
        4  True
        5  True
        6  True
        7  True
        8  True
        9  True
        10 True
        11 True
        12 True
        13 True
        14 True
        15 True
```

Comment: Hello Zeeshan. Please always include code that enables us to instantiate the datastructures in question. People might be ready to fire up an interpreter and play with the dataframe in the process of solving your problem.

Comment: After the `groupby`, you aren't aggregating anything, just checking if all values of `HomeTeam` in each group exist, with `.all()`. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
table_16.Team = res_home.HomeTeam.all().values
```

This will give the correct output.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'team':['a','b','c','d','e','a','c','d','e']})
>>> df.team
    0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    e
5    a
6    c
7    d
8    e
Name: team, dtype: object
>>> a = pd.DataFrame({'team':[]})
>>> a.team = df.team.values
>>> a
   a
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
4  e
5  a
6  c
7  d
8  e
```

`all` is a function which returns True if all elements within a series or along a dataframe axis are non-zero, not-empty or not-False.

Answer (score 0):

table_16.Team = res_home.HomeTeam.all().index 
is the right answer.